# Ordering posts by custom field within another query

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I've googled and tried to figure this out on my own but here goes. I'm querying a custom post type and certain posts within that custom post type with an ID of 180. I then need to order these posts by a custom field. This is my code:

```
$namskeid = new WP_query(array(
                            
                            'posts_per_page' => '6',
                            'post_type' => 'namskeid',
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                array (
                                'key' => 'course_type_display',
                                'compare' => 'LIKE', 
                                'value' => get_the_ID( 180 )
                            ))
                        ));
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I failed to specify meta_type = Date and orderby => 'meta_value_num'.

Here is the code that works:

```
 $namskeid = new WP_query(array(
                        
                        'posts_per_page' => '6',
                        'post_type' => 'namskeid',
                        'meta_type' => DATE,
                        'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'meta_key'  => 'course_date',
                
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            
                            array (
                            
                            'key' => 'course_type_display',
                            'compare' => 'LIKE', 
                            'value' => get_the_ID( 180 )
                        ))
                        
                     
                    ));
```